# How to create a relative frequency histogram

Tags: pgfplots, histogram

I am trying to create a normalized frequency histogram. A minimal working example is adapted from [this TexStackExchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154094/183395) by @Jake (see code below). I know I can switch add density to hist={} but that is not doing what I want. I want to divide the frequency of the specific interval by the total number of observations (here it is 10). The goal is to always have a y-axis that is scaled between 0 and 1. I get

[image: what I get]

but I want (note the epic hand drawn paint zeros on the y-axis :D).
[image: what I want]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
dist
0.00
0.15
0.15
0.25
0.25
0.25
0.40
0.40
0.40
0.40
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=4
]
\addplot +[
    hist={
        density,
        bins=4,
        data min=0.0,
        data max=0.4
    }   
] table [y index=0] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Divide the counts by the total number of observations, like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276201

Comment: @Ross: Thank you for your comment. But dividing by the total number of observations is not a possibility for me. I have too many histograms and manually calculating the total number of observations would be a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of this question: [Histogram in pgfplots: Count the total number of data values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474379/) answered by @Torbjørn T.

His solution uses the `\pgfplotstablegetrowsof` macro from the `pgfplotstable` package to determine the number of rows in the data file. The value of `\pgfplotstablegetrowsof` is then assigned to `\NRows`.

The x-axis values are then produced by dividing the value of the tick by the value of `\NRows` using `yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{(\tick/\NRows)*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%}`.

In his answer, Torbjørn also produces the x-axis labels as intervals, which is also applied here.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
dist
0.00
0.15
0.15
0.25
0.25
0.25
0.40
0.40
0.40
0.40
\end{filecontents}

% Get the number of rows
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}
\pgfmathsetmacro\NRows{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar interval,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=4,
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick},
    yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{(\tick/\NRows)*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
    yticklabel style={
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
      fixed, precision=0,
      /tikz/.cd
    },
]
\addplot +[
    hist={
        density,
        bins=4,
        data min=0.0,
        data max=0.4
    }
] table [y index=0] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for. I also upvoted the original cited duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

one possibilities is define `ytick` and `ticklabels`  manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
dist
0.00
0.15
0.15
0.25
0.25
0.25
0.40
0.40
0.40
0.40
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=4,
    ytick={0,...,4},                   % <---
    yticklabels={0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4}, % <---
]
\addplot +[
    hist={
        density,
        bins=4,
        data min=0.0,
        data max=0.4,
    }
] table [y index=0] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
regarding to OP comment, for the particular case shown in question, y tick labels can be calculated from `\tick`s as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
dist
0.00
0.15
0.15
0.25
0.25
0.25
0.40
0.40
0.40
0.40
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=4,
    yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick/10}                   % <---
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfmathresult}% <---
       },
]
\addplot +[
    hist={
        density,
        bins=4,
        data min=0.0,
        data max=0.4,
    }
] table [y index=0] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But manual labeling is not an option for me. I have a lot of such histograms and I would need to calculate the total amount of observations by hand and then calculate the percentages which would be quite suboptimal.

Comment: @MachineLearner, see addendum in answer.